# How to write case when query in influxdb?

Tags: grafana, influxdb, telegraf, influxql

I have a **Grafana + InfluxDB + Telegraf** setup to monitor my organization's servers. I want to make a dashboard in which I will be monitoring computer resources such as CPU , RAM etc of multiple servers. **I want to show just '0', If my server processor is above 80% and '1', if server processor is below 80% in Grafana dashboard.** For this how can I use **CASE WHEN** statement to show 0/1 depending upon the threshold that I set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*CASE WHEN* doesn't exist in InfluxDB. You have to use math in your InfluxDB query to map value range 1-80-100 into new value range 1-0. Idea:

```
FLOOR(1/(your_cpu_field/80))
```

Doc: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.6/query_language/functions/